# shorten query with whereIn

Tags: postgresql, bookshelf.js

I have a string and an array of string to query postgres database as follow

a string: `'70d8d32d-9ea0-4096-a40f-8df7ea5f1aeb'`
and array of string
`[ 'f2834712-f25c-41ee-80c1-f1e2b2ac1e07', '798670c5-606a-4a22-8961-2bad92ce9a25' ]`

I have to loop the array and query by the separate single string and match by each of the string in array which will produce these two sql

First query:

```
select "id" 
from "TableA" 
where "card_id" = '70d8d32d-9ea0-4096-a40f-8df7ea5f1aeb' 
and "TableA"."location_id" = 'f2834712-f25c-41ee-80c1-f1e2b2ac1e07'
```

Second query:

```
select "id" 
from "TableA" 
where "card_id" = '70d8d32d-9ea0-4096-a40f-8df7ea5f1aeb' 
  and "TableA"."location_id" = '798670c5-606a-4a22-8961-2bad92ce9a25'
```

Then, this is my attempt to simplify the query using bookshelf

```
TableA.query(qb => {
  qb.whereIn(
    `${TableA.prototype.tableName}.card_id`,
    '70d8d32d-9ea0-4096-a40f-8df7ea5f1aeb',
  );
  qb.whereIn(
    `${
      TableA.prototype.tableName
    }.location_id`,
    'f2834712-f25c-41ee-80c1-f1e2b2ac1e07', '798670c5-606a-4a22-8961-2bad92ce9a25',
  );
})
  .fetch({columns: ['id']})
```

But I am not really sure wether this is the right approach

Is there any where I can simplify it in one query using `whereIn` since I already have an array.

Comment: not clear. please show expected results?

Comment: Do you mean something like: `where "stockStorageLocationUuid" = any(array[ 'f2834712-f25c-41ee-80c1-f1e2b2ac1e07', '798670c5-606a-4a22-8961-2bad92ce9a25' ])`

Comment: Expected result has same output as my queries above. The only problem whether I can have single query rather than two separate query. Queries above are produce by Bookshelf. So I want to have cleaner approach of wether to loop the array of string above or I can shorten it within single query. Thank you

Comment: Your current query is already running with only one query. Multiple `qb.whereIn` does not induce multiple queries, knex is a query builder, it is meant to be used that way and will produce a single query. You can verify this using the option `{ debug: true }` in your `.fetch()` call

Comment: I have update my question above. Sorry for my mistake